# Mouse undetected, Graphics crazy - trying to save my dinosaur desktop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, mouse, downgrade

Thanks in advance for your help on this one!

I've been trying to save my HP Pavilion a1540n, retiring it purely to word processing in my office. The sequence of events was triggered when I tried to upgrade to Ubuntu 14 and the desktop environment became very slow (I was warned the graphics card was not supported). Since then I've tried downgrading to several systems (everything from 10-13) and have encountered different but more crippling graphics problems (screen gets frozen blocks of colorful fuzz or other disorganized patterns of color). I've wound up on Ubuntu 11 and my mouse is not responding (although the keyboard is and I can use the terminal). The mouse works in boot repair envt so it's not a physical malfunction. If I could get any operating system where the graphics and mouse are modestly functional I'd be quite satisfied.

Comment: Have you tried Lubuntu? It's specifically designed to be more lightweight, to support older hardware.

Comment: I have not. It's worth a shot, I suppose. I'll give it a go and let you know!

Comment: I did get Lubuntu installed and it works like a charm. I might have to live with it for a while to decide if I like it, but the driver issues were immediately resolved! I expect if I just keep it as a word editing computer with some light web surfing it should work perfectly. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I would personally recommend Xubuntu over Lubuntu, it is also lightweight and it looks nicer.  If you decide to go with Xubuntu, I would recommend version 16.04: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/daily-live/current/

Comment: If you've solved your problem, can you answer it yourself below so other's that have the same issue know the solution?

Comment: Thanks all. My first question experience has gone quite nicely!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with Ubuntu 14.04 probably isn't driver related, it's more likely to be that the demands on your graphics card are too great. As you go back through older unsupported versions, there will be less and less hardware supported, which may explain the mouse problems.

I'd recommend installing either [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) or [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) which are both lightweight desktop environments. [Lubuntu is slightly less resource hungry](https://www.wikivs.com/wiki/Lubuntu_vs_Xubuntu) than Xubuntu, so is often a better choice for older PCs, but it does have quite a plain feel to it. Xubuntu definitely looks more swish. Whichever you choose, I'd recommend downloading LibreOffice for word processing etc.

As a side note, it's generally not a good idea to use an old unsupported release, security fixes aren't maintained, and you can't ask questions about them on Ask Ubuntu either! Using an [LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) version is the best way to guarantee stability in your system, 12.04 and 14.04 are the current LTS releases, and 16.04 is just around the corner (it's in final Beta testing at the moment). Personally I normally wait for the first point (16.04.1) release of a new version to give it time for bugs to be ironed out.